# Overloading template on number of template parameters including literal values

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6988722/1396507) answer provides a `C++11` solution for the problem of *overloading* a template class based on the number of template parameters.

However, this approach seems to work only if the new template parameters are types, meaning  this

```c++
template <typename ... Ts> struct awesome;

template <typename T, typename U> struct awesome<T, U> {};
template <typename T, unsigned int I, typename U> struct awesome<T, I, U> {};

int main() {
    awesome<int,float> aw;
    awesome<int,42,float> aw2;
}
```

[does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3781e08c10c5f4e). Can the desired behaviour achieved using a different approach?

Comment: Could you use `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 42>` instead of `42` to have a type?

Comment: @Jarod42 In principle yes and I've thought about something similar. However, the way I see it, this is somewhat inconvenient and annoying to use when compared to the plain number literal.

Comment: Your code trying to lie to the compiler. The primary template *declares* that it can accept variable number of **type** template arguments, so you've to stick to *that* declaration. If you lie, the compiler will bite you.

Comment: What is "the desired behaviour"? Explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: My intended use-case is an `insert` function for different compile-time type containers. For the `type_list` container, the `insert` struct requires three parameters: The `type_list` (`T`), the index (`I`) where to insert the new type `U`. For the `type_map` container on the other hand, only the `type_map` container and the type to be inserted `U` are required. At the moment the functionality is achieved using two functions `insert_tlist` and `insert_tmap`, so I came upon this problem while trying to unify the interface of the type containers.